# React Native. Custom click handler for TabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

There is a [TabNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab) component in [react-navigation](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation) package.

It handles clicks and activates selected tab. For some tab I want to show a custom screen when a tab is clicked instead of tab activation. I can't find such property in the documentation. Is it doable?